# .htacces file displayed on page

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, include

I got a page where i include a .htacces file to remove php extension from url.

But my issue is that the code displays on the page.

Is it possible to hide it on any ways? The code works fine but peope can se the code on the webpage.

the .htacces file looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you actually including the `.htaccess` file in your PHP page? If so, you can remove that line and it will continue to work.

The `.htaccess` file is interpreted by the webserver (apache), not PHP - and works just by being present in the right directory - it doesn't need to be included into your PHP script.

Comment: Thanks need to wait 9 min to accept. But it wassent included on the main page, but i was including in another page where i included the file... removed it now and it works fine. Thanks again!